# Изменение стиля границ div при наведении на него мыши

Tags: html, css

Есть вложеный в другие элементы `div`, цвет границы которого я хочу изменять при наведении мыши. Однако класс `selectpicture` при наведении на `div` изменяет только курсор мыши на `pointer`, а все остальные элементы остаются неизменными (при чём не только границы, если туда дописать `background-color`, то его я тоже изменить не могу). В чём проблема?

```
<style>
.selectpicture:hover {
    border-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<div style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; position: relative; height: 500px;">
  <div style="float: left; width: 49.51%; height: 450px; background-color: black; border: 3px solid green;" class="selectpicture">
    <div style="height: 400px; width: 100%; background: url('pictures\\games.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%;"> </div>
    <div>
      <p style="font-size: 40px; color: yellow; text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px blue, 2px -2px 5px blue, -2px 2px 5px blue, -2px -2px 5px blue;">Games</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Inline-стиль имеет более высокий приоритет, чем стиль, который задан через класс.

```css
.selectpicture {
  float: left;
  width: 49.51%;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: black;
  border: 3px solid green;
}

.selectpicture:hover {
  border-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; position: relative; height: 500px;">
  <div class="selectpicture">
    <div style="height: 400px; width: 100%; background: url('pictures\\games.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%;">
    </div>
    <div>
      <p style="font-size: 40px; color: yellow; text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px blue, 2px -2px 5px blue, -2px 2px 5px blue, -2px -2px 5px blue;">Games</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть задача не трогать разметку, то можно использовать `!important`. О причинах такого поведения ([специфичности](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)) уже ответили в другом ответе.

```css
.selectpicture:hover {
    border-color: red !important;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; position: relative; height: 500px;">
  <div style="float: left; width: 49.51%; height: 450px; background-color: black; border: 3px solid green;" class="selectpicture">
    <div style="height: 400px; width: 100%; background: url('pictures\\games.jpg'); background-size: 100% 100%;"> </div>
    <div>
      <p style="font-size: 40px; color: yellow; text-align: center; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px blue, 2px -2px 5px blue, -2px 2px 5px blue, -2px -2px 5px blue;">Games</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```